# Google Sheets - Repeat a function a specific number of times

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm new to Google Sheets so excuse me if this isn't super clear.  I have a master document (sheet 2) with a list of names and items for past purchases (sorted by name), for instance:

| Name | Item | Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | Green Tee | Size Medium |
| Joe | Red Tee | Size Medium |
| Joe | Blue Tee | Size Medium |

I then have a separate tab (sheet 1) with a list of names for current orders.  What I want to do is list all previous orders in one cell next to Joe's current order.  So I am looking for a way to lookup all Joe's previous orders and then essentially concatenate them into one cell.

I can write a `Vlookup()` or match and index but I don't know how to make it repeat the specific number of times for each change in person.

I can use the filter function which returns exactly what I want but it spills into the next cells which doesn't work since each row is another person, so the data needs to be confined to one cell / row per person.

Thanks for any help you can give, I know there is a simple way to do this it just eludes me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `TEXTJOIN()` with `FILTER()` function. Try-

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, FILTER(Sheet2!$B$2:$B,Sheet2!$A$2:$A=A2))
```

Or `JOIN()` function like-

```
=JOIN(", ",FILTER(Sheet2!$B$2:$B,Sheet2!$A$2:$A=A2))
```

Reference:

- [`JOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077)
- [`TEXTJOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992)